# Replacing all links in a offline file javascript

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have a offline html file, dynamically downloaded, that I display to the end user with

```
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   echo $line;

}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Is is possible, in javascript or php, I dont mind which, to replace all the links on the page so all the  tags to go to mysite.com/redirct.php?link_here. Thank you for any help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for this you'd be better served saving all the file content to a variable for all the transformations.  fgets grabs data in fixed size chunks, strings may be cut off and it'll be impossible to determine whether they're links.

```
$buffer = '';
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $buffer .= fgets($file_handle);
}
echo $buffer;

fclose($file_handle);
```

Links can be tricky.  Are you forcing everything to start with 'http', or will there be subdomains thrown in?  In any event you're in regex land.  Here's a few to get you started:

```
$buffer = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/.+)\s/U", "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/redirct.php?$1\">$1</a>", $buffer);
```

That says for for any string that begins with 'http://' or 'https://' is a URL for substitution.  The URL ends at the first occurrence of a space character.

```
$buffer = preg_replace("/\s(www\..+)\s/U", "<a href=\"http://mysite.com/redirect.php?http://$1\">$a</a>", $buffer);
```

Similarly, this looks for any string starting with ' www.' and marks it as a URL.

This gets much more complicated with all the different variants of URLs and how they may appear in text, but it should point you towards a solution.

Comment: Using the preg_replace seems to break the css on the site as the sites i am testing on, and will most likely be the ones users try to use with my site, host the css on a different domain to the url.